# SQL, Is there a way iterate through all rows in one column THEN count values, then iterate through all rows in another column and count w/o union

Tags: sql-server, variables, subquery, union

I would appreciate any help in this. I've tried youtube videos and stackOverflow and can not seem to find an answer. I get an error message when I try something similar to below that says something to the effect of you can not aggregate in a subquery,blah, blah,blah.

```
declare @columnname varchar (255)
set @columeName
select id,
count(case when @columnname.[value] in('1','2') then 1 end) as count
from tb
group by id
----The above does not work----
```

I'm trying to avoid doing below:

```
select id,
count (case when columnname in ('1','2') then 1 end) as count
from tb
group by id
union
select id,
count (case when columnname2 in ('1','2') then 1 end) as count
from tb
group by id
```

Comment: Can you include some sample data and an example of what you're expecting the actual outcome to be in certain circumstances?  I must admit that I can't quite understand what it is that you're trying to achieve - ie. what is the business case?  For example, if there were multiple rows with id = "A", and column1 values of 1, 2, 3, and column2 values of 2, 3, 4 - what do you expect to see in the results?  id: A, count: 3?

Comment: In addition we **must** know the dbms vendor because SQL isn't sufficeint to narrow down the specific capabilities of your dbms. e.g. MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, MSSQL all have differences in their implementations of SQL. Edit your tags to add the dbms that is right for you.

Comment: Try an "else 0" after "then 1". Very likely your query engine is confused how to count NULLs.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result. In the query you are avoiding (with "union"), if count from columnname is equal of count of columnname2 - only one line will be shown with the value of each one, and not a sum of both, is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. I sort of solve the first part of my dilemma. In this case, I need to iterate calculations on specific columns within a very large dataset. So, say for example I have one table with the following:

| ID | IndicatorCol1 | IndicatorCol2 | ...300+columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |  |

and turn it into this:

| ID | Indicator_Col_Name | IndicatorCol_OnTrack | IndicatorCol_Total | %_OnTrack |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Indicator_Col1 | 1 | 3 | 33.33 |
| 2 | Indicator_Col2 | 0 | 3 | 0 |

The solution I used is something sort of like this:

```
with temp as 
(select id,col,calculation from 
     (select id, indicatorcol1,indicatorcol2...etc from table) as scr
unpivot (calculations for col in (indicatorcol1,indicatorcol2) 
as unpvt)
select id,col, 
--calculations
count(case when [calculations]= '3' then 1 end) as Indicatorcol_OnTrack, , 
count(case when etc. on calculations...
from temp
group by [id],[col]
order by [id]
```

**If you all have other solutions, I'd be happy to read it! I'm just trying to get rid of all the darn unions I have to do b/c of the plethora of columns in my data set. :/ The next step is I have to figure out how to do a join in here and another group by clause b/c this data gets parsed out even further. ::eek::